# Regular Expression to also allow slash "/" with existing Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am facing difficulty to allow slash "/" with an existing regex

Below is an existing Regex which allows dot and numbers:

```
val.match(/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/)
```

I changes it to...

```
val.match(/^[0-9]+([./][0-9\/]{1,2})?$/)
```

But this one won't allow the number like 1.5/384 where both dot/period and slash simultaneously.

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Maybe you want [`^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?(?:\/\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/HUBxNr/1)? Do you want to match `1/384`? If not, use [`^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2}(?:\/\d+)?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/HUBxNr/2). Can the number after `/` be float?

Comment: Yes, I want to match 1/384 also.

Comment: It doesn't match `1.5/384.6` though.

Comment: @Paul-Etienne It is not necessary. That number is an integer.

Comment: @WiktorStribi Do you guys have any idea about the "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47099406/regular-expression-for-the-email-with-specific-domain-only-in-vbscript?noredirect=1#comment81148704_47099406"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add an optional non-capturing group after your main pattern part to match 1 or 0 occurrences of `/` followed with 1 or more digits:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?(?:\/\d+)?$/
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WIzFBc/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of `.` and then 1 or 2 digits
- `(?:\/\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `/` and then 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

If the number after `/` can be float in the same format as the first number:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?(?:\/\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)?$/
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want :

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\/?(?:\d+\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

See this [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/i6nvT3/3)

**Edit :** Corrected the fact that it didn't match `1` or `1.5`

Comment: Wait a minute, gotta fix this, it doesn't match `1`.

Comment: [`^(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\/?\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/i6nvT3/2) does not match `1` and `1.5` but who cares...

Comment: Doesn't OP care ? Or is it really unnecessary ?

Comment: Haha, not gonna deny I'm kind of looking for SO rep, but I'd prefer if my answers are fully correct :P

Comment: Sure, just please do not duplicate mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157620/discussion-between-paul-etienne-and-wiktor-stribizew).