# Regular Expression for the email with specific domain only in VBScript

Tags: regex, vbscript

Can someone help me with regular expression for the specific domain in VBScript please?

I created one in JavaScript but As per the structure of the existing code, VBScript would be better option.

Regex I created for the JavaScript email validation is

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@testdomain.com$
```

Regex for the VBScript email Validation in VBScript

```
Regex.IsMatch(txtField.txt, "^\d{10}$")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your second regex is only matching a number of ten digits.

Comment: Yeah, But I need help in that section only.

Comment: In what "section"? What doesn't work as expected? What behavior did you expect, and what result did you actually get? What exactly is your question here?

Comment: I am looking for the Regex for the email validation in VBScript. The second code is for the VBScript.

Comment: Hum... What if you copy your js regex and paste it into your VBScript code?

Comment: `Regex.IsMatch` is not VBScript. it is VB .NET code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out. 
The Regex will remain the same.

```
Regex.IsMatch(txtField.txt, "^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@testdomain.com$")
```